# Is there a simplified version of this product

Tags: summation, products, permutation-cycles

How would one simplify the product

$\prod_{i=1}^{N} (a_{i} + 1) $ ? I know that three of the terms would be $ \prod_{i=1}^{N} a_{i} $, $\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_{i} $ , and $1$ . The other terms seem to result from permutations, so would this involve cycles? Thank you for your time.

Comment: For every subset of $\{a_i\}_{1\leq i\leq N}$, there is a term of the product of the elements in that subset in this product (let the product of the empty set be $1$). This fully characterizes the product. As you can see, it is not pretty.

Comment: It involves subsets $J$ of $[N]=\{1,\cdots,N\}$, not permutations: $$ \prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{\substack{J\subseteq[N] \\ |J|=k~}} \prod_{j\in J}a_j \,.$$ The $k=0$ term gives $1$, the $k=1$ term gives $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$, and the $k=n$ term gives $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i$.

Comment: Well that certainly isn't neat. I appreciate both of your responses.